# Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish calls

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

Calls such as:

```
Sfdc.canvas.publisher.publish({name: "publisher.setValidForSubmit",payload:"true"});
```

have started to fail in the one.app after they have been working for a month. They are used to enable/disable the Submit button, etc.

The strange thing is that everything works fine in iOS/Android.

Has somebody started to experience this too ?. Perhaps changes in /canvas/sdk/js/publisher.js that affect the one.app only ?

Comment: A bit more information. I am catching the exceptions thrown by any calls to the publisher -to enable/disable the submit button, and this is the content of the exception: status: 400  statusText: Bad Request  parent version: undefined  payload: client.instanceId or client.targetOrigin not supplied. This only happens with the one.app, and in iOS/Android all works fine. Thoughts ?

Comment: To make things more confusing, this only happens with chrome. In Safari the one.app works fine. We used std chrome and canary and both show the same issue. Pwheeeeeee

Comment: Yes, we're having the same problem as is this fellow https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4X0AAK